# Labelling of exhibits in US criminal court. Why the repetition of letters?

Tags: united-states, evidence, trial

I have been watching a series of videos of a criminal trial in the USA.

I have noticed that exhibits for the defence are labelled with four consecutive letters but often (if not always) these letters are repetitive, e.g. JJJJ and KKKK. I'm on day 5 and have only just realised this so I haven't gone back to watch all the previous videos again in order to check. I'm sure about JJJJ and KKKK.

Here's an example:

> Defence lawyer: *I'm going to  show you what's been marked as defendant's exhibit KKKK.*
>
> [Video: Skylar Richardson Trial Day 5 Witness: Dr John White - Gynecologist Part 2](https://youtu.be/bbceZTVd2hs?list=PLoW1SIeAWaWY7qtlEtzsoRloAB7t6ndZI&t=1068)

**Question**

Why would the labelling have repetition? For example, why might it not be KAAA? Or simply single letters, J, K, L, etc?

At whose discretion/direction are the numbers allocated? The judge's, the counsels?  Is there a standard or does each trial 'invent' its own standard for this?

Answer (score 3):

Different courts have different practices, but I believe the general practice is for plaintiffs to use exhibit numbers, and for defendants to use exhibit letters. As with most procedural questions, the final decision belongs to the judge.

The repetition in letters comes in when you get to the end of the alphabet. After you've used A-Z, you go to AA, BB, CC ... ZZ, then AAA, BBB, CCC, and so on.

Comment: I see - clearly lawyers aren't  mathematicians (with notable exceptions). Does the repetition also apply to numbers, i.e. 1 - 9, 11 - 99, 111 - 999, etc. or do they use ordinary, everyday numbering?

Comment: No, numbers just go normally from 1 to ∞.

Comment: A more efficient way would be this: After Z, you have AA, AB, AC, and so on through AZ, then go on to BA, BB, BC, BD, ...., BZ, then CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, ..., CZ, etc. Maybe lawyers and judges flunked elementary math and didn't think of that?

Comment: In the same way that computer scientists flunked elementary math because they used two-digit designations for years. The exhibit-numbering conventions just came from a time when trials were not so complex that you were ever likely to need that many exhibits.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The problem with that system you start spelling words like AN, AS and AT that might cause confusion.

Comment: @RossRidge : That could be dealt with by punctuation: Exhibit A.C., Exhibit A.D., etc.

Comment: @bdb484 : Still, it seems like an obvious way to do things, to anyone a little bit familiar with math.

Comment: @MichaelHardy the practice was probably established two or three centuries ago.  They didn't have the example of Excel to work with.  Rehearsal letters in large-scale works of classical music often follows the ... Y, Z, AA, BB, ... pattern, and that practice began in the early 19th century or maybe the late 18th.  And what is the cost associated with "inefficient" designations like AAA instead of BA?  It must be quite close to zero.

Comment: @phoog : Your last point may be good, but I think this is more a gap between mathematicians and others than between the 21st and 17th or 18th centuries. I think anyone in the year 1700 who was moderately competent in mathematics as thought about at that time would think of the way I suggested before the way suggested in the posted question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The horse is dead. Stop beating it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Just wait until you see how Massachusetts numbers its laws: Need a section between s. 32 and s. 33? Easy: s. 32A. Between 32A and 33? 32B. Between 32Z and 33? 32AA. Between 32AA and 33? 32BB. Between 172B and 172C? [172B½](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleII/Chapter6/Section172B1~2). It's so bizarre, the website doesn't even get the collation right.